# Specializing only one method of a class template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have a class template that works correctly for all possible types T1, T2.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Basic {
    int a;
    float b;

public:
    void foo(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
        // use a, b, t1, t2
    }
};
```

However, there is one case when `T2` is `char`, and I expect `foo` to behave differently.

So I tried specializing *only* that method:

```
template <typename T1>
class Basic<T1, char> {
    void foo(T1 t1, char t2) {
        // try using a, b, t1, t2 in a very special way

        // ERROR:
        // use of undeclared identifier: a
        // use of undeclared identifier: b
    }
};
```

Problem is, there are potentially a lot of different data members and methods in the template class `Basic`, that are not necessarily related to the function `foo`.

That being said, I feel like full class specialization would be a bloat. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to do something else in `foo`, when `T2` is `char`:

```
void foo(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
   if (std::is_same<T2, char>::value)
     std::cout << "char";
   else
     std::cout << "not char";
}
```

You don't need a full specialization of `Basic` for this, or even a specialization for `foo`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YWSg3u).

From c++17, you can even avoid compiling the branch that is not needed, (i.e. compile the `char` branch only when `T2` is `char`, and vice-versa), using `if constexpr`, like this:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<T2, char>())
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YWSg3u).

Comment: Would be better with `if constexpr` if C++17. Also you're missing a parenthesis.

Comment: @Nelfeal Thanks for spotting the typo. Why would `if constexpr` be needed here? OP has not suggested that there would be uncompilable code in one of the branches.

Comment: @cigien: I would go the other way, why not `constexpr` when it can? but as OP tags C++11, we cannot.

Comment: @cigian Just an optimization. Compare the code generated with or without. It's not available in C++11 anyway, but I wanted to point it out.

Comment: @Nelfeal: optimizers should be able to do the optimization easily.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason to use `if constexpr` here, but added to the answer anyway.

Comment: `std::is_same<T2, char>()` is C++14 apparently. Use `std::is_same<T2, char>::value`.

Comment: @Nelfeal Yes, it appears that's correct. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can branch with `std::is_same<T2, char>`, like `if (std::is_same<T2, char>::value)`, or you can use tag-dispatching, like this:

```
public:
    void foo(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
        foo_impl(t1, t2, std::is_same<T2, char>{});
    }

private:
    void foo_impl(T1 t1, T2 t2, std::false_type) {
        std::cout << "T2 != char\n";
    }

    void foo_impl(T1 t1, T2 t2, std::true_type) {
        std::cout << "T2 == char\n";
    }
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c7a67c4385788cf)